# Can Infinite Scroll jQuery plugin work inside a page?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, scroll, infinite-scroll

I use [infinite scroll](http://infinite-scroll.com/) plugin in my page, but there's a problem: I use it for a content that is hidden in a `div` with `overflow-y: scroll` CSS. Which means that only the div contents are scrolled.

It kind of works, but you need to scroll the whole page to make it download more items. When you scroll only the div, and the page stays in the same place, it doesn't.

Is there a similar plugin, or has anyone hacked it to make it work with scrolling of an element contents?

Comment: It seems you can use it on specific elements. `$('#your_div').infinitescroll({ ... })` doesn't work?

Comment: It works, but you need to scroll the whole page to trigger the plugin to download more items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set

```
behavior: 'local'
```

And set the binder to the element with the overflow indeed.

Answer found here: https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll/issues/151#issuecomment-5222520

Answer (score 0):

As i understood, you needed to add option `binder: $('your div with overflow')`. Then the plugin will start loading content when you scroll inside this div.